# Spark Worker /tmp directory

Tags: apache-spark

Im using spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop-2.7 standalone mode (cluster of 4 workers, 120g memory, 32 cores total)
Although I defined `spark.local.dir` conf param to write to `/opt`, spark worker keep writing to `/tmp` dir, for example `/tmp/spark-e071ae1b-1970-47b2-bfec-19ca66693768`

Is there a way to tell spark *worker* not write to `/tmp` dir?

Comment: If you need some more information, please let me know..

Comment: Can you check `SPARK_WORKER_DIR` environment variable? Start a worker with it set to a directory. You can also use `--work-dir` or `-d` command line options.

Comment: SPARK_WORKER_DIR is by default: `SPARK_HOME/work` in addition to this dir it writes also to /tmp

Comment: Can you check out `java.io.tmpdir` Java property?

Comment: Thank you @JacekLaskowski! thats pointed to `/tmp`, Ill change it.

Comment: Did that help? If so, I'm going to answer your question in a proper way for future readers.

Comment: I passed this property as `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` and I see some files written to `/opt`, But I still see files also written to `/tmp`. When looking at environment page on the spark ui, I see this change only on the `Spark Properties` table and not in `System Properties`..

Comment: You are configuring Spark worker (not executor) so `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` may or may not have any meaning. I haven't checked myself. You should change the JVM property of a Spark worker (slave).

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, is there a way to pass worker config like `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` and `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions`? thanks

Comment: Yes, there is, but a Spark worker is **not** interested in them. You are configuring a Spark worker not a Spark executor. They're different. What really are you trying to do? Did `java.io.tmpdir` help?

Comment: As you said I configuring by mistake spark executor instead of worker, when adding this configuration on the executor I saw some file written to `/opt` but still saw some data also written to `/tmp`.. (Maybe its related either to shuffling configuration or to failed spark tasks).. I just want to point all my outputs to other path location...

Comment: I have the same issue. Setting "spark.local.dir" and "java.io.tmpdir' to any other directory does not solve the issue of Spark writing to /tmp directory. Any new updates on this?

Comment: I tried using this like : pyspark-shell --driver-memory '16g' --executor-memory '16g' --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true 
 --conf spark.sql.parquet.cacheMetadata=False --master local[4] 
 --conf spark.local.dir=/apps/dmg/spark-temp/ -Djava.io.tmpdir=/apps/dmg/spark-temp/

still no luck. it is going to /tmp again

Answer (score 0):

As per the [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html), few environment variables will override the property 'spark.local.dir', please try checking these environment variables

Quoting from the documentation:

> spark.local.dir
>
> Directory to use for "scratch" space in Spark, including map output
> files and RDDs that get stored on disk. This should be on a fast,
> local disk in your system. It can also be a comma-separated list of
> multiple directories on different disks. Note: This will be overridden
> by SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS (Standalone), MESOS_SANDBOX (Mesos) or LOCAL_DIRS
> (YARN) environment variables set by the cluster manager.